# How to add a custom domain to Azure File Share?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-file-share

I'm working on an Azure File Share for my project and I would like to configure a custom domain name for it. However, I'm not sure about the exact steps and best practices for achieving this. Can someone provide guidance or point me in the right direction?

Specifically, I want to do the following:

1. Add a custom domain (e.g., **`files.mydomain.com`**) to my Azure File Share.
2. Ensure that the custom domain is properly mapped to my Azure File Share.
3. Configure SSL/TLS for secure access to the custom domain.

I have already set up the Azure File Share, and it's working with its default URL, but I need to make it more user-friendly with a custom domain.

Any help or documentation links would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I referenced the following blog to add a custom domain to Azure File Share:
https://jenishms.medium.com/ef272e252fbf